# How hierarchical are Delphi 2009 project configuration option sets?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

Delphi 2009 introduced a hierarchical system for project options configuration, where you set "base" options and then have different build styles with their own option sets. But can you extend the hierarchy even further? I do most of my coding with debug options on, of course, but sometimes there are special cases where I want a slightly different set of debug options. I'd really like to be able to set up a basic debug configuration and then three more specific configurations underneath it, but I can't find any option to do this.  Is it not possible in D2009, or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's straightforward.

In the project manager, just right-click on the "Debug" configuration, and select "New Configuration". Your new configuration will appear as descended from "Debug" in the way that you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Build Configurations are completely hierarchical.  You can create any depth of hierarchies that you want in your configurations.  Any build configuration can be descended from, and the hierarchies can be as deep as you like.

In addition, you can use Option Sets to alter any given configuration.  Save an Option Set in a file and apply it to any configuration that you like at any time.

I think it is safe to say that the Build Configuration System in Delphi 2009 is about as flexible and powerful as you'd want it to be.